# What should I use, get_posts or wp_query for less CPU load?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I have a blog and on the main page are 3 blocks of posts. So, I get these posts with "get_post" and I have 3 similar codes on page:

```
global $post;
$args = array( ... );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
.......
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have a hight load of CPU and I wonder if I will use "wp_query" will save my CPU.
Thanks.

Here are my get_posts() queries:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => "1"   );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 7, 'offset'=>0, 'category' =>"2 , 4 , 6 , 7 , 9 ,10,11");
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array('size' => 300,300), array('title' => '')); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 15, 'orderby' => 'rand' ,'offset'=>0, 'category' =>"31");
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Do you have still high CPU load when you comment out these loops/queries?

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 2):

I doubt using `get_posts()` vs `WP_Query()` would make any meaningful/noticeable difference in CPU load. Ultimately, [`get_posts()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/post.php#L1726), anyway:

```
$get_posts = new WP_Query;
return $get_posts->query($r);
```

You would be better served by looking at the efficiency of the queries themselves; but to provide specific assistance there, we would need to see each of your `get_posts()` queries.

Answer (score 2):

All queries are eventually wrappers of `WP_Query`, and while some are better than other ( never use `query_posts` ), the performance differences of `get_posts` vs WP_Query are negligible.

The strict answer would be that `WP_Query` is faster, but the margin by which it's faster imperceptably small as to not be worth the optimisation.

***If you have high CPU load, switching between `get_posts` and `WP_Query` is not the solution***

I recommend viewing this slideset by the core developer Nacin that explains when and how queries should be used, and why:

http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012