# Show only one post for each author ( Page loads too slow )

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql

I want to show only one latest post by each author and found this code that it working. However, it takes too long to load the page since I have over 100K authors and 100K posts in database. How can I optimize this code?

```
<?php
  //Displaying latest post per author on front page
  function filter_where($where = '') {
    global $wpdb;

    $where .= " AND wp_posts.id = (select id from {$wpdb->prefix}posts p2 where p2.post_status = 'publish' and p2.post_author = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_author order by p2.post_date desc limit 0,1)";
    return $where;
  }
  add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
  query_posts($query_string);

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

...
  ?>
```

Here is an original article for the code.

http://www.dbuggr.com/smallwei/show-latest-post-author-wordpress-front-page/

Answer (score 0):

Wow! A subquery in the `WHERE` clause! That is a nasty one. :)

I can't test this right  now (on the phone, this all memory) but let me see what I can do. I think that all you need is a `GROUP_BY` filter:

```
function group_by_author($groupby) {
  global $wpdb;
  return " {$wpdb->posts}.post_author";
}
add_filter('posts_groupby','group_by_author');
```

Then create a new `Wp_Query` with other relevant arguments -- not `query_posts`! Not ever!

Proof of concept:

```
function group_by_author($groupby) {
  global $wpdb;
  return " {$wpdb->posts}.post_author";
}
add_filter('posts_groupby','group_by_author');

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'ignore_stickie_posts' => true,
  'order' => 'ASC',
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q);
if ($q->have_posts()) {
  while ($q->have_posts()) {
    $q->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_author();
    echo '<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but nothing shows up on the page. Here is my code. what am I missing? http://grab.by/HOL0

Comment: I'll have to test later

Comment: after looking through your previous answer (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78117/query-to-return-maximum-of-one-post-per-author?rq=1), removing GROUP BY seems to be working but ended up at the same issue that it shows the oldest post instead of latest. Also pagination will get messed up cause it still does calculation on total number of posts.

Comment: @Ohsik : see the edit.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I just tried that code and this is what I get http://grab.by/HR2K. does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: Please note that the code is proof of concept, as specifically noted. It isn't meant to be used unmodified. Comment the `var_dump`, to start.

Comment: It still selects the oldest post from each author. Other than that, I still need to figure out how to implement pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just tested and it works perfectly. You'll also want to remove pagination from the author template.

I haven't tested it, but have you tried pre_get_posts?

```
function author_filter($query) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
  if ($query->is_author()) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
   }
 }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','author_filter');
```

Comment: I just tested it but it does not filter out posts from an author. It suppose to show only one latest post by author. Here is my code http://grab.by/HOK8

Comment: This is actually a category list page. that will show list of a latest post by all the users who have posts. That is why I need pagination on the page.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were in the author template. You may have already seen it, but have you tried any of the solutions here? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78117/query-to-return-maximum-of-one-post-per-author?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the link. I just tried that but no luck on my situation.